# Do I need exec to run findByIdAndDelete and findById. What is their return value?

Tags: mongoose

I am using version `^7.4.0`.

The documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query() ) says that `Model' functions` findByIdAndDelete`and`findById`return`Query`. I noticed at other places that after calling these functions,` exec` needs to be run.

Question 1 - However, I am able to run these functions without calling `exec`. Do I need `exec` to run these functions?

Question 2 - What is the return value of `findByIdAndDelete` and `findById` when the are successful or when they fail? I can't find the information in the documentation.